# Beamer's \pause doesn't delay hyperref's borders

Tags: beamer, hyperref, pause

When using `\pause` in `beamer`, link borders created by `hyperref` will appear even if the link text and the link itself (in `\href{}`) both appear *after* the `\pause`. How can I delay the border until the link text actually appears?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\hypersetup{colorlinks = false, urlbordercolor = 0 1 0, pdfborder = 0 0 .5}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    Here a link will appear:\pause
    \href{https://www.google.com/}{Google}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I might be wrong but I guess this is only possible with `\only` if you excuse the pun `\only<2-4>{\href{https://www.google.com/}{Google}}` such that beamer can throw away the contents for other slides.

Comment: @percusse You're right. `\only` causes problems with the alignment of `\item`s, though, but I've been playing with this and found a trick, which is to first use `\pause`, and then put only the `\href{}` within the scope of `\only`. Care to add an answer?

Comment: I think you should answer yourself as I didn't understand what you did with `\pause`

Comment: Ok, will do ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As percusse mentions in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262651/beamers-pause-doesnt-delay-hyperrefs-borders#comment629868_262651), `\only<>` will delay the border created by `hyperref`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\hypersetup{colorlinks = false, urlbordercolor = 0 1 0, pdfborder = 0 0 .5}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item A link will appear below:
    \only<2->{\item \href{https://www.google.com/}{Google}}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

A well-known problem with `\only`, however, is that it changes the placement of previous `item` lines when the `\item` within the scope of `\only` is added, because `beamer` can't see that item until it finally appears, after which it has to push previous `\item` lines up to make room for the new `\item`.

To avoid this, it's best to use `\pause` before the `\item` (because then `beamer` can 'see' it), and only let the `\href{}` link be within the scope of `\only`. Since `\href{}` takes up no space in the output anyway, it will have no effect on the placement of items or text.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\hypersetup{colorlinks = false, urlbordercolor = 0 1 0, pdfborder = 0 0 .5}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item A link will appear below:\pause
    \item \only<2->{\href{https://www.google.com/}}{Google}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```